# How to delete user settings when reinstall C#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to delete user settings while uninstalling? 
After the upgrade, I want the programme  to delete all of the old settings and replace them with new ones. I tried this, but not working:

```
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateRequired)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
            Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateRequired = false;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using _Properties.Settings.Default.Reset()_

Comment: Yes, but when I reinstall program the bool Properties.Settings.Default.UpdateRequired is still false so programm does not enter to loop...I also tried with another WindowsFormApp and Custom Action Uninstall but second App does not refer to first Properties.Settings.Default

Comment: It is _false_ because default value for bool is _false_. Create property UpgradeNotRequired and compare it to _true_ instead.

Comment: Thank you for help but still the same thing. Let me explain it in details.
When I start the programme for the first time after first installation, there is a bool names "Number"  that equals 10 (and this number is saved in user settings). The user can change this value (e.g. to 99).
While reinstalling the programme, I'd like the "Number" variable to be equal to the value from the installation file ( I want this value to change e.g. to 10).

Comment: Each time I reinstall the programme the Number is still 99, which was previously entered by the user, remains unchanged (but I'd like it to change to a default value). My point is that I don't know how to reset the properties during the re-installation.